# SQL - Hacer consultas por días específicos por nombre

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero saber si existe la forma o parámetro para consultar en un rango de fechas especificando el nombre del día; ejemplo: filtro por fecha del día 1 al día 31, quiero ver los días lunes de ese rango colocando únicamente la condición 'lunes'.

Comment: Sí, sí es posible, hay una forma. Con un [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) puedes recibir una respuesta puntual. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

Si es posible.

Puedes valerte de la función [`datename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) en la cláusula `where` de una consulta, de la siguiente manera:

```
select CampoFecha
  from TuTabla
 where datename(weekday, CampoFecha) = 'Lunes';
```

Para ponerlo a prueba, he construido un ejemplo que encontrarás más adelante y en el que realizo lo siguiente:

- Establezco el idioma de la sesión a Español con la cláusula [`set language`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). De otra manera la consulta podría fallar al devolver la función los nombres de los días en otro idioma.
- Declaro dos variables que contienen la fecha inicial y final de la consulta
- Construyo una serie de CTE's para ir armando la solución

  - El primer CTE, llamado `Consecutivo` se vale de la tabla sys.all_columns para construir una secuencia de números que va de 0 a aproximadamente 10,000 en una base de datos típica, lo cual permitirá que la siguiente consulta sea capaz de generar información para aproximadamente 27 años, de ser necesario por el rango de fechas.
  - El siguiente CTE, llamado `Dia` utiliza el rango de fechas definido en las variables `@FechaIni` y `@FechaFin` junto al consecutivo y genera una lista de todas las fechas existentes entre estas.
- La consulta final toma todas las fechas del CTE `Dia` y las filtra, de manera que muestra solo los días Lunes contenidos en el rango de fechas. Para ello se vale de la función [`datename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) con el intervalo `weekday`, que nos devuelve el nombre del día de la semana de una fecha.

Si comprendes su funcionamiento, puedes tomar de estos elementos los que te sean útiles para construir la solución a tu necesidad particular.

```
set language spanish;

declare @FechaIni date = '20230101';
declare @FechaFin date = '20230131';

with 
Consecutivo as (
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as I from sys.all_columns
)
, Dia as (
select dateadd(day, I, @FechaIni) Fecha
  from Consecutivo
 where dateadd(day, I, @FechaIni) <= @FechaFin
)
select Fecha, datename(weekday, Fecha)
  from Dia
 where datename(weekday, Fecha) = 'Lunes';
```

El resultado obtenido para el intervalo del 1 al 31 de enero de 2023 es:

```
Fecha      
---------- ------------------------------
2023-01-02 Lunes
2023-01-09 Lunes
2023-01-16 Lunes
2023-01-23 Lunes
2023-01-30 Lunes

(5 rows affected)
```